# How to write an apostrophe in a char

Tags: c#, types, char

I need to store an apostrophe in a char how would I do this?

I’ve tried using double like when storing quotes in a string but that didn’t work and I can’t find an answer online

This is in C# in case you didn’t look at the tags

Comment: oh... we look at the tags. Also can you be more specific (edit your question), give an example

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want

```
var myAwesomeChar = '\'';
Console.WriteLine(myAwesomeChar);
```

Output

```
'
```